# Is it okay to handle user permissions client side only in a web application?

Tags: reactjs, permissions, authorization, roles

I'm building a web application for sports leagues. A league profile page is created by the user where they can manage the league (add teams, approve final scores, post announcements, etc.). The user that created this page should be the only one able to perform those actions. Other users can visit the profile meaning READ ONLY.

in the `leagues` table of the database there is a foreign key column called `owner_id` that references the `users` table id column.

In the scenario where a user wants to add a team to the league, is it okay to perform this code on the client side? This would be the only code checking whether the user is authorized. Do I need server side code as well? How would I do that without opening another database connection?

```
async function AddTeam(){
    if(user.id === league.owner_id){
      ///api call
    }
  }
```

The user id is available when they log in. The league owner_id is available when the league profile page is visited.

Comment: You have to do it on the server side. The client code is fully in the hands of the user, so assume a malicious actor could change it in any way possible, including sending modified requests to the backend.

Comment: @Nick That makes sense. For UI purposes I am guessing it is okay to do that simple if statement check, right?

Comment: Yes, the `if` statement is perfectly fine for the UI, just make sure you're protecting things on the backend!

Comment: @Nick If I am sending the user's id along with the leagues owner_id in the request to do a comparison on the backend, what's stopping someone from modifying the request if they know the user id/owner_id of something they want to tamper with? I don't see how doing this on the backend is more secure than doing on the front end because of this.

Comment: You shouldn't validate the user's identity based on any information they submit. You should get it based on a cookie or JWT or some other token that your backend can use to lookup the user's identity

Answer (score 2):

Option 1) It is better to handle user permissions at the server side using node js .

- Like create node API to post the user information data from UI to the node
  API.
- In the node API make the Main API call for db update, get the data.

In the API call request add headers with who is the user updating the database.

Add authorization headers for better tracking of who is updating the data.

Option 2 ) You can use oAuth implementation and add the scope(get,post,put,delete) to the user for the operation on updating the database or to get the data .